# How to delete data without losing them

Tags: sql, postgresql

There is two tables:

1. STUDENTS (STUDENT_ID, GROUP_ID)
2. GROUPS (GROUP_ID, NAME)

I need to write query that delete students from specify group (suppose there is group with 'target_id') without losing any data.

I try to explain another words. One student can learn in many groups. One of that groups is group with 'target_id'. If we delete student he disapears from ALL groups. But I need that this student disapears only from one group.

Same thing with groups - query shouldn't delete any of them.

Comment: Have a link table student_group with the student id and the group id. When removing from a group, simply remove the relevant row from the link table.

Comment: **[EDIT]** your question and add the query you were using. Some sample data and the expected outcome would be helpful as well. [**Formatted**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) **text** please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Comment: `DELETE FROM students s WHERE s.group_id IN(SELECT t.group_id FROM groups t WHERE t.group_id = s.group_id)` ?

Comment: @JonStirling: the `students` table (if that is the complete column list) looks very much like a link table

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Could be true, but if so that's some terrible table naming.

Comment: Fixed* `DELETE FROM students s WHERE s.group_id IN(SELECT t.group_id FROM groups t WHERE t.name = 'target_id') ?`

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing is a many-to-many relationship.  This is usually modeled by creating a third table

```
STUDENT_GROUP
STUDENT_ID     GROUP_ID
```

and then you would remove GROUP_ID from the STUDENTS table.  That way both a student and a group exist independent of any student-group-membership records.